# Winforms: Open a second modal dialog in an already open modal dialog

Tags: .net, winforms, modal-dialog

I have an open **modal dialog** and open again a modal dialog from this dialog (with ShowDialog) The problem is now that the **parent modal dialog** is **not locked** and when I click on it the second modal dialog, it moves to the background. When I close the first modal dialog, the second one still remains on the desktop. How can I prevent this behavior or what is the problem with this scenario?

Comment: This isn't how `ShowDialog` is supposed to work. Can you paste the part of your code that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have set the dialog's Owner property.  This tells WinForms/Win32 which window to disable when the new window goes modal.  Do something like this:

```
secondDialog.Owner = firstDialog;
secondDialog.ShowDialog()
```

Or, try calling `secondDialog.ShowDialog(firstDialog)`, which should set the owner chain for you.

Comment: +1 You should virtually always pass an owner parameter to `ShowDialog`